# AWS CodeDeploy not running hooks scripts

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm learning how to use CodePipeline and have problem with CodeDeploy for small testing node app. My target is to implement CD for large express + react app and I need to use hooks from AppSpec.yml.
For now everything else is working, files are copied etc, it just doesn't fire script. I started with BeforeInstall (delete process from pm2) and ApplicationStart (start app with pm2) hooks, but now I switched to using ApplicationStart with script to remove process from pm2 just to see if it works.

My AppSpec.yml:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/api
permissions:
  - object: /home/ubuntu/api/
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
    mode: "777"
# I use appStop.sh just to check if this works:
ApplicationStart:
  - location: scripts/appStop.sh
    runas: ubuntu
# I tried also running as root, still nothing
    timeout: 60
```

appStop.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/api
pm2 delete 0
```

I tried many things, also running everything as root (though I prefer to use ubuntu user).

There are no ERRORs in log file in /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent.

I can also see all files and scripts dir in reviev in /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/...

When I manually run appStop script in home dir it works.
It looks like CodeDeploy agent is just not running script.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems I made it work.
First I cleaned codedeploy-agent data by removing `/opt/deployment-root/<deployment droup id>` dir and `/opt/deployment-root/deployment-instructions`

I also changed location, don't know if this helped, but had to do it since I decided to go with root user to make things easier. App is now in /var/www/api.

I also reinstalled all js software (node, pm2, npm) using `sudo`

My *working* AppSpec.yml:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/api

permissions:
  - object: /var/www/api/
    mode: 775
    type:
      - file
      - directory
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/appStop.sh
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/appStart.sh
      runas: root
```

and *working* scripts:

appStop.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/api
sudo pm2 delete 0
```

appStart.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/api
sudo pm2 start server.js
```